# Webpack doesn't serve the images

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader

I got trouble with webpack. My config here – https://gist.github.com/lavezzi1/801d5d3f2d2f5dfebb8efd234cedb9ab

If I write something like 
`<img src="./static/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">`

in my html file my image doesn't serve, I mean I can't see it in development mode.

I use this command for serve `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"`. But if I write the same code inside of vue file it server correctly. Also works perfectly when I build it for prod.

What's wrong? How to serve images in dev mode? Thanks.